# angular 4 setting dropdown option values received from api

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular4-httpclient

**html:**

```
<div *ngIf="myBooks">
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let book of myBooks" name="state">{{book.state}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
 <p>{{ selected }}</p>
</div>
```

**component:**

```
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../../create/createservice';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {State} from '../../create/model';
import {City} from '../../create/model2';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http/src/response';

@Component({
selector: 'app-add.dialog',
templateUrl: '../../dialogs/cityadd/add.dialog.html',
styleUrls: ['../../dialogs/cityadd/add.dialog.css']
})

export class AddDialogComponent1 {

constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddDialogComponent1>,
          @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data1: City,
          public dataService: DataService,private httpService:HttpClient) { 
  }

myBooks: string [];
selected = null;

formControl = new FormControl('', [
Validators.required
// Validators.email,
]);

states: string[];
city:string[];


 ngOnInit () {
  this.httpService.get('api/state-city').subscribe(
    data => {
      this.myBooks = data as string [];     // FILL THE ARRAY WITH DATA.
    },
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.log (err.message);
    }
  );
 }
```

This is my code i want to select values which is there is in this api but i am not getting any values please help me how to bind it

in my api i have `'state'` name i want that values in the dropdown list how to get it

Comment: what are the error you are facing?

Comment: nothing i am not getting any error but i am not getting that mat-select field only

Comment: you want to get selected value by the user?

Answer (score 2):

Declare array of myBooks as:

```
myBook : any[]=[]
```

and pass value of data on that :

```
this.myBook = data
```

It will work!

Comment: can you show/say me what data has return?? also check and compare if you have material "mat-select" is wrong on this link [Plunker Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/W4uUCHD4Ms25HJ7FngzV)

Answer (score 0):

you are using selected as a ngModel. You should assing the value whihc need to be selected.

here in your code you are assigning a null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you declare `myBooks: string [];` as array of strings. And later in your `*ngFor` loop you tried to access them as an array of object `book.state`

So declare `myBooks: any [] = [];` later make sure the api is responding the data u r expecting.

I hope this helps,

Comment: show me your api response .
Also what is the error ?